# Issue with build "dlib" to Xcode

Tags: xcode, dlib

I have to try to use dlib for my project.
However, when I try to build it, I receive a message about:

> "_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives"

For solving this issue

1. I tried to add it new project
2. I deleted every existing path or data
3. I tried to build it on "Release mode"

I have still receive a message:

> "_USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives"

Please, solve my curiosity!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [link](https://github.com/zweigraf/face-landmarking-ios) for dlib integration. Also check the following things for configuration.

1.Header search path for the lib folder. for e.g. **$(PROJECT_DIR)/lib** where lib folder contains libdlib.a and dlib header files.

2.Check the **Preprocessor macros** in build setting whether properly
    set or not.

3.Create the Objective c++(change **.m** to .**mm** extension) wrapper class which can execute both c++ and objective c code.

***Note**  import dlib header files in wrapper class not in the main.m or app-delegate otherwise it will gives error.

Also check the [Reference](https://github.com/zweigraf/face-landmarking-ios/issues/7).